# Current is defined as rate of flow of charges, but charge is a physical "property", then how can it flow?

Tags: electric-current, charge

I am confused as to whether charge is something that physically exists (like matter is, i.e. it occupies space and has mass) or just a measurable property, after reading the mentioned definition.

Comment: I think your confusion is mainly *philosophical.* Philosophical terms to be weary of are, "reality", "exist", etc. They're loaded with preconceptions. Charge is as "real" as it gets in physics. It is strictly conserved (never changes); and it is a so-called superselection observable (cannot have an indefinite value due to quantum superposition).

Comment: What is the difference between "something that physically exists" and "a measurable property"? Your explanation in the brackets does nothing to clarify this - we certainly say that e.g. photons "exist" but they have no mass.

Answer (score 3):

A flow of charges just means something that contains charge is "flowing" or moving.

Edit: Charge is a property. Electrons or anything else that has the charge will create electricity when moved.

Answer (score 1):

Current is measured in Amperes (A) which is equivalent to one Coulomb (C) per second, i.e.
$$
1 \ A = 1 \ \text{C/s},
$$
where Coulomb is the measure of charge. Imagine you have a bunch of electrons in a wire. Each electron is negatively charged with a value of $q = -1.60217662 \cdot 10^{-19}$ C (this particular value is usually called the elementary charge). Now, if the electrons in the wire are moving, you could count how many electrons move past a given cross-section of the wire per second, or similarly, how much charge is moving past the cross-section per second. In this sense, charge can flow.

Answer (score 0):

Current is defined as the rate of flow of charges through a specific cross section in space (i.e a wire).

Comment: How can a charge flow when it is a property(an attribute) of matter?

Comment: The charges themselves (electrons, etc) physically moving through space p

Comment: Oh so does it mean that in reality, when we say charges flow, we mean that the elementary particles whose property is charge are moving?

Comment: @PoorvajaJain yes.